# How to print date in symfony from mysql

Tags: php, symfony

```
<?php foreach($sessiondetailsdatas as $sessiondetailsdata) { ?> 
<tr class="even pointer"> <td class=" "><?php echo
$sessiondetailsdata->getSession(); ?></td> <td class=" "><?php
print_r($sessiondetailsdata->getStartDate()); ?></td> <td class="
"><?php print_r($sessiondetailsdata->getEndDate()); ?></td> <td
class=" "><?php echo $sessiondetailsdata->getDescription(); ?></td>
</tr> <?php } ?
```

and the result for date is

```
DateTime Object ( [date]
 => 2015-04-01 00:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Asia/Calcutta )
```

now how can i get only date?

Comment: Any reason you haven't checked the documentation for the `DateTime` class?

Comment: In mysql there is a DATE syntax where u can get date from datetime field. Can you try that. For example: " select  DATE(datetime_field) as alias_name from tablename;" And u can use this in your php file

Answer (score 1):

In mysql there is a DATE syntax , from where you can get date from datetime field. You can try that. For example:

```
select DATE(datetime_field) as alias_name from tablename;
```

And u can use this in your php file

Comment: If you found it is useful. Can you please mark it as useful answer?

Comment: can i print it using get() method?

Comment: I dont know about php methods. Using mysql query result in php variable, you can get date into a variable from a datetime field

Comment: i am implementing it in symfony2. so i want to use it in get() method.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a DateTime Object like in your example, you can use `format()` to format the date in any format accepted by PHP's `date()` you like.

So

```
$sessiondetailsdata->getEndDate()
```

becomes

```
$sessiondetailsdata->getEndDate()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

for example.

If you use Twig it's even easier to handle dates:

```
{{ entity.startDate|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}
```

which also uses the same format() function of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
Example controller class file code:
-------------------------------------------
public function getUserDetailAction($idUserDetail)
{
    //For example to get user birthdate
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $userDetail = $em->getRepository(
        'DemoBundle:UserDetail')
        ->find($idUserDetail);

    $userBirthDate = $userDetail->getBirthDate()
        ->format('Y-m-d');

    //echo $userBirthDate;

    return $userBirthDate;
}
I hope this example would be useful to understand how to get and print date in symfony.
```